# combine multiple rows in one cell based on groups

Tags: python, csv

I have a csv file format like this:

```
user1 , group1
user2 , group1
user3 , group2
user4 , group2
```

I want to use python to have the following result:

```
group1, user1 user2
group2, user3 user4
```

How can I do it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `groupby` and a `lambda` function to join the text strings.

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame({'user': {0: 'user1', 1: 'user2', 2: 'user3', 3: 'user4'}, 
                   'group': {0: 'group1', 1: 'group1', 2: 'group2', 3: 'group2'}})
df.groupby('group')['user'].apply(lambda x: ' '.join(x))
```

```
group
group1    user1 user2
group2    user3 user4
Name: user, dtype: object
```